# Why is it not possible to search/insert/delete in O(1) time?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

Why are there no data structures that can support search/insert/delete in O(1) time?

Comment: Your question is flawed - you can have data structures that search, insert or delete on O(1) time. E.g. a linked list permits inserts and removals in O(1) time, as you just need to change a couple of pointers. An array allows you to search by array index in O(1) time.

Comment: No, why isn't there a data structure like BST O(log n), B-trees or Fibonacci heaps that can support O(1) time for all search/insert/delete functions?

Comment: @Naomi If you are asking for a mathematical proof, you will have to ask a very precise question. Do you want to know why a tree cannot operate in O(1)? Do you have an algorithm you want to calculate complexity for? Also, it's actually very simple to create a data structure for insert/delete in O(1). The problem is that memory complexity can increase fast.

Comment: @sulthan If a data structure can support > or < comparisons, why can it not be O(1) time?

Answer (score 0):

Hashtables behave in O(1) on average if the hash function is designed properly. But of course, in worst case, hashtables are O(n), e.g. if the hash function returns the same value for all elements.

Comment: can you elaborate on that please?

Comment: For the sake of mathematical proof we usually suppose the hash function is uniform and the input is randomized. Also, it's pretty common to select a hashing function randomly (universal hashing), thus preventing bad data (similar to randomized quick sort). In that case the asymptotic complexity is really 0(1).